# Clarification about statements like $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \exists x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in {A},\forall i\in\{1,...,n-1\},x_i<x_{i+1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers

When I see a statement like:

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \exists x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in {A},\forall i\in\{1,...,n-1\},x_i<x_{i+1}$

The formal meaning is that:

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \exists x:\{1,...,n\}\to  A,\forall i\in\{1,...,n-1\},x(i)<x(i+1)$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right, as sequence is a function whose domain is countable.

Comment: It depends... In predicate logic, we often use $x_i$ as *variables*. They are part of the language, i.e. symbols.

Comment: I'm never happy when *formal* is used  together with "$\ldots$"